# How many spark tasks are created for a word count job in below scenario

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to know how many tasks are created for a simple word count job for the below scenario.
So First I will explain the scenario with my understandings

```
    rdd=sc.textFile("/user/pathirippilly/sample_data_mr/wordCount.txt",5) # so RDD with 5 partitions
    pipeRDD=rdd.map(lambda x : x.split(" ")).flatMap(lambda words : map(lambda word : (word,1),words)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
     pipeRDD.collect()
```

If you consider the DAG of stage for above code,we have

```
    stage1:

    rdd.map(lambda x : x.split(" ")).flatMap(lambda words : map(lambda word : (word,1),words))

    stage2:

    reduceByKey(lambda a,b : a+b)
    pipeRDD.collect()
```

Now say while doing spark submit, I have asked for 512mb of executor-memory and 2 executors.
Also assume , I am having 10 node cluster with each worker node is having minimum of 32 GB of RAM

So Cluster Manager(YARN) will surely allocate a single worker node since I am only asking only 2 JVM containers of 512 MB heap memory size.

Now My questions are

> 1.As per architecture, how many number of partitions are there , that many number of tasks are there.So here if we see , I can understand 
>   stage1 (which involves only narrow transformations) need to be applied
>   on each partitions.So here entire stage 1 will form a single task or
>   in stage1 itself , it will split into multiple tasks?
>
> 2.Lets say executor1 is handling 3 partitions and executor2 is handlind 2 partitions.Does this imply that on executor1 3 stage1 tasks
>   and 3 stage2 tasks are performed? For executor2 simlary 2 stage1 tasks
>   and 2 stage2 tasks are performed?
>
> 3.Say I am having 5 partitions in 5 nodes.So during a shuffling or sorting phase ,surely data in these partitions need to be
>   interchanged. How spark is achieving this ? Is there any good
>   explanation or video link is available for this?

Comment: Why wouldn't the second `map` be another stage? BTW, you're welcome to check the Spark/YARN UI to see what stages are actually ran

Comment: @cricket_007 second map is also a narrow transformation right , so obviously it will be on stage 1 right?

Comment: Again, feel free to look at the Spark UI and you should be able to answer that yourself

Comment: Note: transformations alone don't do anything, and you're missing an action, so no stages are created with the given code

Comment: Yeah ..That I understood. Say If I add . collect () or some other action.wthether , I will be able to know , how may stages are created  and how many tasks are there in each stage . As per architecture, if a wide transformation is involved , spark will create a new stage for that.Thats why I have added a second stage for reduce By Key

Comment: I have just checked the Web UI and found that total of 2 stages and 10 tasks are executed in a single worker node.Every stage 5 tasks.So for every partition 1 task. And  First stage is for reduceByKey and second is for collect(). And it has used an executor for driver program first and for every stage it added 2 executors. So my doubt is why the first two map (map and FlatMap) functions are not in picture ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183134/discussion-between-akhil-pathirippilly-and-cricket-007).